# Tree storing multiple values per node

Tags: data-structures, find, binary-tree, treenode

I'm trying to find a way to create a binary tree where 3 doubles are stored in each node and another tree where 6 doubles are stored in each node.

The problem I'm having is figuring out a way to implement find and insert methods (no need for  remove).

Basically, my tree is holding x, y, z values and when I call find, I want it to return the node which contains x, y, and z values closest to those I am trying to find.

How should I be approaching this problem and what are some ideas for a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: What language are you implementing this tree in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for [**k-d tree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) data structure, which also allows [finding nearest neighbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Nearest_neighbour_search) to a given element.

Comment: I think you are probably right, @amit, in that OP is looking for something to help in 3D-ish thingy.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class BinaryTreeNode<T>
 {
    public T Value {get; set;}

    public BinaryTreeNode<T> Left {get; set;}
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> Right {get; set;}

    public BinaryTreeNode<T> Seach(T forWhat)
    {
       if(Value == forWhat) return this;

       BinaryTreeNode<T> leftResult = Left.Search(forWhat);
       if(leftResult != null) return leftResult;

       BinaryTreeNode<T> rightResult = Right.Search(forWhat);
       if(rightResult != null) return rightResult;

       return null;
    }
 }

 BinaryTreeNode<Tuple<double, double, double>> threeDoublesTree = new BinaryTreeNode<Tuple<double, double, double>>();

 BinaryTreeNode<Tuple<double, double, double, double, double, double>> sixDoublesTree = new BinaryTreeNode<Tuple<double, double, double, double, double, double>>();
```

Comment: How will it find nearest neighbor for an entree? care to elaborate?

Comment: You mean exhaustively? won't the time consumption of it be linear in the number of elements in the tree? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Linear? Not necessarily.  @Joshua, are you storing the value tuple in some order or not? [see this about the Big-O](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/recurrence.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you store 1 value per node. You can treat those x, y, z values as 3D points. On the left of one node you putpoint closer to (0, 0, 0) and on the right you hold further ones. If you have structure like this you can search and insert data as you would in ordinary binary tree.